# Retrieve and modify an entity without maintaining a database context?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm new to the Entity Framework. I'm using to work with the database in a WPF application. I've created a model as in [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx), and I now want to use it in my application.

I know how to retrieve and modify entities like this:

```
DatabaseContext ct = new DatabaseContext();
var person = ct.Persons.Find(1);
person.Name = "NewName";
ct.SaveChanges();
```

However, in an application that waits for user input, this means keeping the datacontext around in the ViewModel, which isn't very desirable. Instead, I want to do something like this:

```
class PersonViewModel {

    Person psn;

    public PersonViewModel(int PersonId) {
         DatabaseContext ct = new DatabaseContext();
         psn = ct.Persons.Find(1);
    }

    public Save() {
        DatabaseContect ct = new DatabaseContext();
        ct.Persons.Update(psn); // (There is no Update() method.)
        ct.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

I don't know how to do `Update()`.

I have the DatabaseContext defined like this:

```
public partial class DatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

but I don't seem to have `DatabaseContext.ObjectStateManager`, which some people use in solutions to similar problems. I don't know why this is - is it related to using POCO objects?

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to Attach:

```
public Save() {
    DatabaseContect ct = new DatabaseContext();
    ct.Entry(psn).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ct.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really well. I've seen some articles suggesting using `Attach()`, but I couldn't find a good way of changing the `EntityState` with this method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Attach()` method. More details you can find here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896248.aspx

```
 ct.Persons.Attach(psn); // instead of Update()
```

Things may become more complicated because attached object will be in Unchanged status and you'd need to update it to Modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Attach method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx).

```
public Save() {
    using(DatabaseContect ct = new DatabaseContext())
    {
      ct.Persons.Attach(psn);
      ct.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```